# Implemented a basic dictionary in python using lists as linked list and murmur hash as a hash function

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, hash-map

```
import mmh3
from random_things import string_generator


class HashMap:
    def __init__(self, num_of_buckets=4, load_factor=0.75):
        assert (num_of_buckets >= 1)
        self.num_of_buckets = num_of_buckets
        self.mp = [[] for i in range(num_of_buckets)]
        self.LOAD_FACTOR = load_factor
        self.num_of_elements_in_ht = 0
        self.longest_chain = [-1, -1]

    def bucket(self, key, num_of_buckets):
        k = mmh3.hash(key)
        return k % num_of_buckets
        # return HashMap.my_own_hash_function(key) % 3

    def _does_it_need_resizing(self):
        return self.num_of_elements_in_ht / self.num_of_buckets >= self.LOAD_FACTOR

    def resize(self):
        if self._does_it_need_resizing():
            new_hash_table_size = self.num_of_buckets * 2
            new_hash_table = [[] for i in range(new_hash_table_size)]
            for linkedlist in self.mp:
                for element in linkedlist:
                    bucket_index = self.bucket(element[0], new_hash_table_size)
                    new_hash_table[bucket_index].append(element)
                    if len(new_hash_table[bucket_index]) > self.longest_chain[0]:
                        self.longest_chain = [len(new_hash_table[bucket_index]), new_hash_table[bucket_index]]
            self.num_of_buckets = new_hash_table_size
            self.mp = new_hash_table

    def set(self, key, value):
        bucket_index = self.bucket(key, self.num_of_buckets)
        element = self._get(self.mp[bucket_index], key)
        if element:
            element[1] = value
            return element
        self.mp[bucket_index].append([key, value])
        if len(self.mp[bucket_index]) > self.longest_chain[0]:
            self.longest_chain = [len(self.mp[bucket_index]), self.mp[bucket_index]]
        self.num_of_elements_in_ht += 1
        self.resize()
        return [key, value]

    def _get(self, bucket, key):
        for ele in bucket:
            if ele[0] == key:
                return ele
        return None

    def get(self, key):
        bucket_index = self.bucket(key, self.num_of_buckets)
        get_resp = self._get(self.mp[bucket_index], key)
        return get_resp[1] if get_resp else None

    def remove(self, key):
        bucket_index = self.bucket(key, self.num_of_buckets)
        for ele in self.mp[bucket_index]:
            if ele[0] == key:
                self.mp[bucket_index].remove(ele)
                self.resize()
                self.num_of_elements_in_ht -= 1
                if len(self.mp[bucket_index]) < self.longest_chain[0]:
                    self.longest_chain = [len(self.mp[bucket_index]), self.mp[bucket_index]]
                return

    def get_the_entire_map(self):
        return self.mp.copy()

    @staticmethod
    def my_own_hash_function(key):
        return 0

    def get_longest_chain(self):
        return self.longest_chain

    def num_of_elements(self):
        return self.num_of_elements_in_ht

    def keys(self):
        k = []
        for linkedlist in self.mp:
            for element in linkedlist:
                k.append(element[0])
        return k


def main():
    mp = HashMap(2, load_factor=1)
    # mp.set("my_string", "my_string")
    # mp.set("my_string2", "my_string")
    # mp.set("my_string3", "my_string")
    # mp.set("my_string4", "my_string")
    # mp.set("my_string5", "my_string")
    # mp.set("my_string6", "my_string")
    # mp.set("my_string7", "my_string")
    # mp.set("my_string8", "my_string")
    # print(f"Size of map {len(mp.get_the_entire_map())} and number of elements is : {mp.num_of_elements()}")

    import time
    import random
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        for my_count, my_string in enumerate(string_generator(20, random.randint(10, 50000))):
            mp.set(my_string, my_string)
            mp.set(my_string, my_string)
        if time.time() - start >= 1:
            print(
                f"Size of map {len(mp.get_the_entire_map())} and number of elements is : {mp.num_of_elements()}. Longest chain {mp.get_longest_chain()[0]}")
            time.sleep(0.200)
            # start = time.time()
        for key in mp.keys():
            mp.remove(key)
        if time.time() - start >= 1:
            print(
                f"Size of map {len(mp.get_the_entire_map())} and number of elements is : {mp.num_of_elements()}. Longest chain {mp.get_longest_chain()[0]}")
            time.sleep(0.200)
            start = time.time()
        mp = HashMap(2)

    # for idx, val in enumerate(mp.get_the_entire_map()):
    #     print(idx, len(val))

    # print(mp.set("my_string", "my_string1"))
    # print(mp.get("my_string"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## cite your references

```
from random_things import string_generator
```

What is the meaning of this?
We need a `# comment` in the source code describing its provenance.

Based on [pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports)
and how you wrote this, you're telling the Gentle Reader
that this dep comes from a library outside of the current project.
If that's not accurate, use
[isort](https://pypi.org/project/isort)
to clarify your intent.

(OTOH your reference to [mmh3](https://pypi.org/project/mmh3)
was very clear, thank you, as MurmurHash is available on pypi.)

---

## extra parens

```
    def __init__(self, num_of_buckets=4, load_factor=0.75):
        ...
        self.num_of_buckets = num_of_buckets
```

This is perfectly nice and bog standard.

Consider renaming the first parameter so we assign like this:

```
        self.num_of_buckets = initial_num_of_buckets
```

That would stress that the caller is only offering a hint,
and is not bound to that many buckets over the map's lifetime.

```
        assert (num_of_buckets >= 1)
```

No.
Please elide the extra `(` `)` parentheses.
Suppose we get a feature request in future for
displaying the actual number upon failure.
We wouldn't want to trick some poor maintenance engineer
into accidentally writing the following erroneous code:

```
        assert (num_of_buckets >= 1, num_of_buckets)
```

---

## comments where appropriate

```
        self.longest_chain = [-1, -1]
```

That's rather cryptic.
Offer a hint about how to interpret that 2-tuple.
And consider using `tuple` rather than `list`.
Bonus points for a self-describing
[namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Later on the whole cryptic `ele[0]` thing is
tedious and would similarly benefit from
a self-describing datastructure.

```
        self.mp = [[] for i in range(num_of_buckets)]
```

Sorry, you lost me there.
No idea how I should mentally pronounce "mp".
Please offer the Gentle Reader a clue about those two words.

(I really hope it isn't a vowel-less form of "map".
To avoid shadowing a builtin we conventionally append
an `_` underscore, giving `map_`.)

Similarly, tell us about "ht" (`num_of_elements_in_ht`).
Wouldn't you like to use the conventional name of `size` ?

EDIT
Further down in the code you reveal it is a Hash Table.
I'd been expecting Hash Map based on the class name, whatever.

---

## use object attributes

```
    def bucket(self, key, num_of_buckets):
        k = mmh3.hash(key)
        return k % num_of_buckets
```

Ummm, sorry, you lost me there.
Why did we pass in 2nd parameter?
Instead of `return k % self.num_of_buckets` ?

EDIT
OIC, `resize` could have doubled `self.num_of_buckets` early,
but instead chose to do it late.
Consider doing it earlier, prior to looping.

```
        # return HashMap.my_own_hash_function(key) % 3
```

Commented out code is fine during debugging.
But you're requesting review for a PR merge-to-main,
and that's the right time to prune such things from the source
before showing it to others.

---

## use accurate names

```
            for linkedlist in self.mp:
```

I see what the identifier is trying to tell me,
but it's not clear to me that we have a
[linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)
of nodes that each have a `node.next` field.
If you had wanted that, I would have expected the import of
[deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

```
    def resize(self):
```

Consider renaming this to `maybe_resize`,
since often the call will be a no-op.

---

## use a None sentinel

```
    def _get(self, bucket, key):
        ...
        return None
```

Wow, I didn't see that one coming.
A `HashMap` is like a `dict`,
but one cannot store a `{"foo": None}` value?!?
And `set` doesn't complain when given a `None`?

App-level programmers are going to want to use `None`.
Recommend you create your own `none_sentinel = object()`
so you can `return` and test against that.

---

```
    @staticmethod
    def my_own_hash_function(key):
        return 0
```

World's greatest hash function, I know.
In a """docstring""" you might spell out that this
is for testing. Plus this gives you a great opportunity
to specify what you expect of a hash function,
e.g. whether negative return values are acceptable.
Minimally you should annotate:

```
    def my_own_hash_function(key: str) -> int:
```

---

## public attributes

```
    def get_longest_chain(self):
        return self.longest_chain
```

Ok, I bit my tongue on the map .copy() thing,
but this is even more silly.
This public method is absolutely not pulling its weight,
given that it offers access to a **public** attribute.
Either rename to `self._longest_chain`
or delete this method.

```
    def num_of_elements(self):
        return self.num_of_elements_in_ht
```

Yup, not getting that one, either.
I would expect this **container** to
conform to the `Sized` protocol,
so that `len(my_map)` would be
how an app developer accesses this.
Suggesting a name of `def __len__`.

---

## offer a generator

```
    def keys(self):
```

This method is lovely, thank you.

It allocates storage proportional to map size.
Consider offering a `yield element[0]` generator instead.
If someone really needs a list they can just request `list(my_map.keys())`,
same as they would for a `dict`.

---

## loop where appropriate

```
    # mp.set("my_string8", "my_string")
```

Same remark as above -- review time is when we clean up comments.

But even before you commented it out, a `for` loop would
have been a much more convenient way to stimulate
the system-under-test.

---

## stress the code

```
enumerate(string_generator(20, ...
```

I'm guessing we insert twenty keys.

That's great during manual testing when you're trying
to initially get things working, so you're not
visually overwhelmed by a data dump.

Now that it works and you're obtaining timings,
I encourage you to fill it with many more keys.
That way if an operation isn't O(1) or O(N)
it will show up in the timing data.
I'm concerned this code may be rather on the slow side.

Publishing a self-evaluating
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
as part of this codebase wouldn't hurt.

---

This code appears to achieve its objectives.

Given a few trivial renames I would be willing to
delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for all the valuable suggestions. I agree with all of them. There are few things I did to check if my map is working correctly. I have two queries 1. What is the right place to resize() a hashmap? 2. I have tried benchmarking and as the hash function seems to be deciding factor. Do you see this implementation being much slower than the official stdlib dict? I do understand it being implemented in C and having bindings to python. There are a lot of optimizations that would be in the native dict as well. So far I am not accounting for real edge cases.